String List<DataRow> DropdownButton selected 1st value is shown in all rows
I am using flutter datatable and I have a string list.
If your list count is 5, then you will see five rows.
Each row contains a dropdown.
After you select a value in the dropdown, then problem is that the selected value is shown in all 5 rows. This is not the correct behavior.
This is b/c I am not using index which has the int type.
I don't know how to incorporate index so that each row will show a different selected list item.
I've read that I should use something like this: myList.indexOf(element).
With the indexOf, I cannot use int index b/c element is a string.
Could you please provide your suggestions.
I have the following code - this code only shows the first list item a1.
static List<String> myList=['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5'];

int getlistRowsCount(){
   return myList.length();
}

Widget mytable = Container(child: SizedBox(height: 500, child:DataTable(columns: [
          DataColumn(label: Text('My heading')),
        ],
        rows: List<DataRow>.generate(getlistRowsCount(),(index) => DataRow(cells: [
          DataCell(DropdownButton<String>(value: dropdownvalue,onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                 setState(() {
                   dropdownvalue = newValue!;
                 });
               },
                   items: myList.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String xyz) {
                     return DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: xyz,child: Text(xyz));
                   }).toList()))
             ]))
        )));


haven't got your requirement properly, but If i had to use N-Dropdown, I will use a map<category,DropDownItems> to generate rows

After you select a list value in the dropdown, you see the first value a1 in all rows. This is not the right behavior. I need to understand where in the code to use (index) to see a different value on each row.

The reason behind updating all dropDown button is using single value for all value: dropdownvalue.  To control specific item, you need to use a list based on your snippet.
List<String> myList = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'];
  int get itemCount => myList.length;
   
  ///setting null value initially
  late List<String?> selectedValue = List.generate(myList.length, (_) => null);

  /// use method instead of variable for context consistency 
  Widget mytable() => Container(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 500,
          child: DataTable(
            columns: const [
              DataColumn(label: Text('My heading')),
            ],
            rows: List<DataRow>.generate(
              itemCount,
              (index) => DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(
                  DropdownButton<String>(
                    value: selectedValue[index],
                    onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                      selectedValue[index] = newValue;//updating here
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    items: myList.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                      (String xyz) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: xyz, child: Text(xyz));
                      },
                    ).toList(),
                  ),
                )
              ]),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );


I get the error: RangeError (length): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

it will be due to your data fetch, make sure selectedValue having the equal(with null) as myList length

I have the question about this code: items: myList.map<DropdownMenuItem>(
(String xyz) {
return DropdownMenuItem(value: xyz, child: Text(xyz));
},
).toList(), - (String xyz) is a single value, but I need to do: (String? list[i]). Instead of showing a single value, I need to show List[i] value. How do I do that? thank You
